# nth-child not targeting the correct element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```css
.test:nth-child(1),
.test:nth-child(2),
.test:nth-child(3) {
  color: #0F0
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="reuinIt">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dkfj2xzj/13/ <- *UPDATED* with my jQuery code if it helps

Why is it not skipping the `.ruinIt` class and not targeting the third `.test`?
I'm adding `<div>`s dynamically and when a `<div>` without the `.checkDrop` class is added I **need** to skip it.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: All you need is `.test > p {color: #0F0}` or `.test > * {color: #0F0}`. No need for `nth-child` selector. At least in the current state of the question.

Comment: I'll show you the Jquery code I'm using:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkfj2xzj/13/
So I need it to skip every element without the .checkDrop class. Is it possible?

Comment: The Divs are added dynamically

Comment: You want to do this with CSS or the jQuery? Here's an example where I apply a green border to every input without the `checkDrop` class: https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/eyp4duj9/2/

Comment: I want to do this with Jquery.

Comment: Your fiddle is not clear to as what exactly you want to do...but I wish you good luck in finding a solution to your problem!

Comment: I updated the post, I don't know if it clears things up.
A save button will copy the HTML to a new DIV. To give sliding checkboxes the correct values it needs to target the .checkDrop DIVS from the first DIV (using drag and drop to sort elements). Therefor I want the first div of its type to transfer the value to the first one in the new DIV. But if I add multiple and add a textarea in between them, it will  still target the DIV without .checkDrop class. Does it help? :P Sorry, my english is not that great and I'm probably just assuming you guys know what I'm doing, haha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because the `nth-child` selector does not mean it's the *nth* of that specific class. It means that it's the *nth* sibling overall.

So the `nth-child(2)` refers to your `.reuinIt` class, however, it does not also have the `.test` class and therefore it does not receive any styling.

Your **last** `.test` class is the `nth-child(4)` however that has no styling rules applied.

If you'd like to see a working example, I've updated your [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dkfj2xzj/10/).

---

## EXAMPLES

### The :nth-child

The important thing to remember here is that the `:nth-child` selector specifically targets HTML elements based on their index/position inside their containers/parent elements.

Have a look at the example below and take note of how the corresponding commented `:nth-child` selector's index continues to increment regardless of the type of element it's targeting.

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>   <!-- h1:nth-child(1) -->
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>   <!-- p:nth-child(2)  -->
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>   <!-- p:nth-child(3)  -->
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>   <!-- h2:nth-child(4) -->
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>   <!-- p:nth-child(5)  -->
</div>
```

---

### The :nth-of-type

The cool thing about `:nth-of-type` is that it ignores all of the other elements that are not of the same type, i.e. if the element you are targeting is a `<p>`, it will ignore all of the surrounding "non-`<p>`" elements when calculating its index.

The below example will provide you with a basic understanding of the indexing rules that `:nth-of-type` follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>   <!-- h1:nth-of-type(1) -->
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>   <!-- p:nth-of-type(1)  -->
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>   <!-- p:nth-of-type(2)  -->
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>   <!-- h2:nth-of-type(1) -->
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>   <!-- p:nth-of-type(3)  -->
</div>
```

---

### A little more complexity with :nth-of-type

It is however very important to remember that `:nth-of-type` bases it's indexing values on the **HTML Element Type** regardless of the CSS Class you are using to call the property.

Have a look at the below example:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>                    <!--        h1:nth-of-type(1) -->
    <p class="my-class">Paragraph 1</p>   <!-- .my-class:nth-of-type(1) -->
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>                    <!--         p:nth-of-type(2) -->
    <h2 class="my-class">Heading 2</h2>   <!-- .my-class:nth-of-type(1) -->
    <p class="my-class">Paragraph 3</p>   <!-- .my-class:nth-of-type(3) -->
    <h1 class="my-class">Heading 3</h1>   <!-- .my-class:nth-of-type(2) -->
</div>
```

This example is a little more complex, but it helps if you see CSS Declarations as a sort of *filtering* rule. For example, if create a CSS declaration by typing:

```
p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I am essentially telling the browser 2 things:

1. Only `<p>` tags should be affected and,
2. Only if they are the second `<p>` tags amidst their siblings

The difficulty comes in when I write CSS that looks like this:

```
.my-class:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

By **not specifying an element type**, my rule essentially reads with the following filter:

1. Only elements with the class `my-class` should be affected and,
2. Only if those elements are the first sibling of their type of elements.

If were to apply the above CSS to the HTML in the example ([see fiddle for working example](https://jsfiddle.net/frits_steyn/hez2Lnry/)), we would get an output that looks like this:

[image]

In the output above, you'll see that both the first `<h2>` and the first `<p>` elements were affected regardless of whether or not their siblings had the `my-class` class name applied.

Comment: I'm sure it's not needed, but if you'd like to see what I mean, here's your fiddle that I've corrected: https://jsfiddle.net/dkfj2xzj/10/

Comment: Shouldn't the dot be removed in your example; `.p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}`?

Answer (score 2):

The code `.test:nth-child(2)` doesn't mean "the second element of the class `test` in its container". It means just "element that has a `test` class *and* is the second child of its container".

The behavior you expected can be expressed with [CSS Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-nth-child-pseudo) as `:nth-child(2 of .test)`. Unfortunately, this syntax is currently supported [only in Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-nth-child-of).

Answer (score 2):

Try below code for targeting nth-child:

You can first parent div for all child div.

```css
.parent_div .test:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
.parent_div .test:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
.parent_div .test:nth-child(4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_div">
<div class="test">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="reuinIt">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey nice , our thought are same

Answer (score 1):

`.test:nth-child(2)` selector means select an element having class `.test` when it is 2nd child of its parent. Similarly `.test:nth-child(3)` will select 3rd element of a parent if it will have `.test` class.

In your case 2nd element doesn't have `.test` class so it is not selecting it. If you wants to target them 3rd `div` element you need to use `.test:nth-child(3)`(As it is 3rd element of its parent, not 2nd).

Correct selector will be:

```
.test:nth-child(1), .test:nth-child(3), .test:nth-child(4) {color: #0F0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```css
.test:nth-child(1),
.test:nth-child(2),
.test:nth-child(3) {
  color: #0F0
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>
  <p>Test</p>

</div>

<div class="reuinIt">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test:nth-child(1), .test:nth-child(3), .test:nth-child(4)
{color: #0F0}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Test0</p>
</div>
<div class="reuinIt">
  <p>Test1</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Test2</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>Test3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confused between the usage of **nth-child** & **nth-of-type**. nth-child will consider all the tags and all the elements. If you want to specifically count a certain type of element or class, don't make use of nth-child. Go for nth-of-type. But, moreover ***nth-of-type is not supported currently for the classes*** though it works fine for html tags (may be in future it will get supported). All you need to do is change the nth-child numbers to 1, 3, 4. That's the only way you can get your results.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jw66uj1p/

```
.test:nth-of-type(1),
.test:nth-of-type(3),
.test:nth-of-type(4) {
  color: #0F0
}
```

Comment: In terms of CSS selectors, 'type' is almost a synonym for 'tag name', selectors like `div` are called 'type selectors'. So `:nth-of-type` references only elements of the same tag name by definition, it doesn't have anything to do with classes. There is a form of `:nth-child` in CSS Selectors 4 that takes classes/IDs/attributes into account (`:nth-child(An + B of .something)`), but it works only in Safari.